# Массив, возрастающая последовательность

Tags: java, массивы

Всем доброго времени суток, подскажите почему мой код не работает?

Нужно проверить является ли массив возрастающей последовательностью, я написал такой код:

```
boolean sequence = false;
    String rus;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[i + 1]) {
            sequence = true;
        } else {
            sequence = false;
        }
    }
    if (sequence == false) {
        rus = "Нет";
    } else {
        rus = "Да";
    }
    System.out.println("Является ли массив возрастающей последовательностью? " + rus);
```

Comment: что значит не работает?

Comment: определяет неправильно, массив не с возрастающей последовательностью, а пишет что - "Да"

Comment: а что такое array и зачем тут String rus?

Comment: array - массив. String rus переменная, чтобы true и false написать по-русски.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, удивительно, что он не вылетает с ошибкой "Выход за границы массива", но ваша проблема не в этом. Флаг `sequence` становится истинным каждый раз, когда какой-то элемент массива больше следующего. То есть, если конец массива - возрастающая последовательность, то `sequence == true`.

Чтобы исправить данную ошибку, нужно понять, что если хоть какой-то элемент массива не меньше, чем следующий, то условие строгого возрастания последовательности уже не выполняется, а поэтому нужно просто выйти из цикла в этот момент:

```
boolean flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (a[i] < a[i + 1])
        flag = true;
    else
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Но лучше сократить этот код следующим образом:

```
boolean flag = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (a[i] >= a[i + 1])
    {
         flag = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый пример очень помог разобраться что вообще происходит.

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях может возникнуть ошибка `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` в условии `array[i] < array[i + 1]`.

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
int[] array =
        new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
boolean sequence = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
        sequence = false;
        break;
    }
}

String rus;
if (sequence) {
    rus = "Да";
} else {
    rus = "Нет";
}
System.out.println("Является ли массив возрастающей последовательностью? " + rus);
```